# Rock, Paper & Scissors

Tags: c++, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

Thanks for your time, I am new to programming and I spent some days making this rock, paper & scissor game. What other possible improvements could I make after the ones I've made myself?

I've tried explaining each step as the program goes on, but I essentially at first generate a computer pick (i.e. **R**ock, **P**aper or **S**cissor), then ask the user for their pick (i.e. `rock`, `paper` or `scissor`), compare the two and depending on the game rules (Rock vs Paper results in a loss for the Rock), output the game result.

Again, this is my first try at it. Some improvements I've already added myself are: `getline` instead of `cin`, use of functions and switches, shortened the code and merged outputs in little space.

Thank you for helping a new-entry at coding.

#### main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //variables.
    string usrPick;
    string stringResult;
    char randPick = fnc.randPick(); //generates the first random pick.
    int gameCountr = 0;
    //beginning of the program.
    cout << endl << "GAME " << gameCountr << " ~ ";
    while (getline(cin, usrPick) && ++gameCountr) {
        //variables.
        char gameResult = fnc.gameResults(fnc.toChar(usrPick), randPick);
        //converts game result to readable text.
        switch (gameResult) {
            case 'e': stringResult = "even";
                break;
            case 'w': stringResult = "won";
                break;
            case 'l': stringResult = "lost";
                break;
            default: stringResult = "?";
                break;
        }
        //prints out the choices and who won the game.
        cout << "you: " << fnc.toChar(usrPick) << " / computer: " << randPick << " / " << stringResult << endl << endl << endl;
        //generates a new random choice.
        randPick = fnc.randPick();
        //prompts the user to input their choice to play again.
        cout << "GAME " << gameCountr << " ~ ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.h

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class exercise2 {
public:
    char toChar(string word);
    char randPick();
    char gameResults(char usr_ch, char cmptr_ch);
private:
    char outp_s;
};

exercise2 fnc;

//converts to char the user input.
char exercise2::toChar(string inpt_s) {
    //reinitializes value.
    outp_s = NULL;
    if (inpt_s == "rock") {
        outp_s = 'R';
    } else if (inpt_s == "paper") {
        outp_s = 'P';
    } else if (inpt_s == "scissor") {
        outp_s = 'S';
    } else {
        outp_s = '?';
    }
    return outp_s;
}

//generates a random choice for the computer to play.
char exercise2::randPick() {
    //variables.
    vector<char> vctrOptions = {'R','P','S'};
    //chooses a random value in the given pool of values.
    return vctrOptions[rand() % vctrOptions.size()];
}

//prints out the game results.
char exercise2::gameResults(char usr_ch, char cmptr_ch) {
    //variables.
    outp_s = NULL;
    //checks user input and applies game rules.
    switch (usr_ch) {
        case 'R':
            switch (cmptr_ch) {
                case 'R': outp_s = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'P': outp_s = 'l';
                    break;
                case 'S': outp_s = 'w';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'P':
            switch (cmptr_ch) {
                case 'R': outp_s = 'w';
                    break;
                case 'P': outp_s = 'e';
                    break;
                case 'S': outp_s = 'l';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'S':
            switch (cmptr_ch) {
                case 'R': outp_s = 'l';
                    break;
                case 'P': outp_s = 'w';
                    break;
                case 'S': outp_s = 'e';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            outp_s = '0';
            break;
    }
    return outp_s;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/214577/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: note to reviewers- this was originally posted [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54953209/1575353) - while it may be closed as _off-topic_ there soon, it currently has [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953303/1575353)

Comment: Seems you come from Java regarding your Java-ish programming style. Not everything has to be in a class in C++.

Answer (score 2):

- [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- You forgot to include `<string>` and `<cstdlib>`.
- `exercise2` is not a very clear name.
- Why is `exercise2 fnc;` global?
- `char exercise2::toChar(string inpt_s)` can be by const ref instead of by value.
- `outp_s = NULL;` avoid `NULL`, see http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null
- You use a `switch` later but not here, why?
  Moreover you read in a `string` but then "convert" it to `char` instead of simply checking once if it's e.g. *r* or *rock*.
- You throw away your vector of choices everytime you call the function. Consider keeping it as a member instead.
- Look at `<random>` if you need randomization.
- `gameResults` is convoluted, you should look into another way of handling the logic.

Too many `char`s and too many `switch`es. Some of your comments are unnecessary.
Try improving your program and ***after*** you did that you can look at this [incredibly nice implementation of RPS by user **Edward**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213842/rock-paper-scissors-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of random suggestions. See if any of these are helpful.

- Make the prompt more explicit to the user, maybe: 'enter rock or paper or scissors or quit: '
- It is considered good practice to not use 'using namespace std:=;', instead prefix all the std symbols with std::.  So std::cout, std:cin, std::end, etc..  For an initial and small project 'using namespace std;' seems okay.
- Have the compiler report warnings.  For clang these are some good flags: '-Wall -Wextra -Weverything'
- out_s should be declared as a char. so 'char outp_s = NULL;'

Comment: -Weverything just gives you pages and pages of noise. The other two are OK though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, decouple internal and external representation. This allows for efficient and elegant implementation of the game-logic, as well as easing any changes to the user-interface you might ever want to make.

```
enum status { TIE, WIN, LOSS, UNKNOWN};
enum symbol { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, UNKNOWN};

constexpr status resolve_game(symbol user, symbol gaia) noexcept {
    return (3 + user - gaia) % 3;
}

constexpr symbol to_symbol(std::string_view s) noexcept {
    return s == "rock" ? ROCK
        : s == "paper" ? PAPER
        : s == "scissors" ? SCISSORS
        : UNKNOWN;
}

constexpr std::string_view to_string(symbol s) noexcept {
    constexpr std::string_view names[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors", "?", };
    return names[s];
}

constexpr std::string_view to_string(status s) noexcept {
    constexpr std::string_view names[] = { "tied", "won", "lost", "?", };
    return names[s];
}
```

Having done that should allow you to make the rest much nicer.

---

A couple points to coding-style:

1. Use `nullptr`, never `NULL`. The latter can cause ambiguity.
2. Namespaces `std` is not designed to be imported wholesale, so desist.
3. Only use `std::endl` if you really need to flush the stream. And in that case, prefer `std::flush` to demonstrate your conscious choice.
4. Header-files are for declarations, some `inline`-implementations, the rare preprocessor-macro and certain other constants. General function- and variable-definitions belong in implementation-files.
5. The name is an integral part of any symbol, and well-selected names clarify the code and obviate the need for most comments.
6. When you have the choice, avoid heap-allocations, even if properly encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In a for statement would it be better to initialize the counter ‘i’ with a number or a nullptr? How do I go to the next line making inaccessible to the user the previous lines without std::endl (apart from ‘\n’)? Being obviously learning this language for just less than a month I’m struggling with your piece of code, how would I proceed implementing it in my little game?