# C++ practice project: Blackjack

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, playing-cards

For the longest time I always felt lost designing a robust OOP program, especially in C++. I felt like I didn't know enough theory or algorithms so I would study and never write code, not to mention I was always afraid of criticism or looking amateurish. Recently I came to the realization that I been holding myself back by doing this and moving beyond my insecurities. I have taken more leaps by writing common C++ programs to build my knowledge of the language and architecture. Everyone told me writing a Blackjack game would help build my knowledge purely for practice for more ambitious projects and contributing to open source projects that is hard for me to understand.

**TL;DR:** I been creating a Blackjack program to help me learn programming and design at a more advanced level.

I tried utilizing things I never used before such as namespaces, enums, and maps with operator overloading. Right now it's a work in progress: it only handles 2 players, the dealer logic hasn't been developed yet until I get the game working correctly, thinking about making a derived class for Blackjack rules in case I want to make poker rules. I already know this is a mess, but I guess it's part of the learning process, huh?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BlackJack.h"
#include "Player.h"

int main() {
    BlackJack game(2); // only two players for now, requires user for both
    game.play();
    return 0;
}
```

CardInfo.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace Cards {
    enum class Rank {
        ONE = 1, TWO, THREE,
        FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE,
        TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
    }; 
    enum class Suit { 
        CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES 
    };
};

namespace CardData {
    // TODO make a derived card class specifically for Blackjack rules
    struct Card {
        Cards::Rank rank;
        Cards::Suit suit;

        // TODO define this so the map works
        bool operator<(const CardData::Card &card) const {
            return this->rank < card.rank;
        }

    };

}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "CardInfo.h"

class Player {
    int points{ 0 };
    int numAces{ 0 }; // count aces in order to deduce 1 or 11 logic in updateScore
    int id;
    std::vector<CardData::Card> hand;

public:
    Player(int ID);
    void dealtCard(CardData::Card &drawnCard);
    void updateScore(int score); // call after every dealt card
    bool requestHit(); // request to exchange cards
    bool hasBust();
    int getScore();
    int getId();
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Player::Player(int ID) : id(ID) {}

void Player::dealtCard(CardData::Card &drawnCard) {
    //Card drawnCard{ Cards::Rank::ACE, Cards::Suit::SPADES }; remove possibly
    hand.push_back(drawnCard); // test insert
}

void Player::updateScore(const int score) {
    if (score == 11)
        numAces++;

    points += score;

    if (points > 21)
        while (numAces > 0) {
            numAces--;
            points--;
        }
}

bool Player::requestHit() {
    char answer;
    std::cout << "Player " << id << ": Hit or stick? [y|n]" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> answer;
    return tolower(answer) == 'y';
}

bool Player::hasBust() {
    return getScore() > 21;
}

int Player::getScore() { return points; }
int Player::getId() { return id; }
```

BlackJack.h

```
#pragma once
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include "Player.h"
#include <string>

class BlackJack {
    int numPlayers;
    static std::unordered_map<Cards::Rank, int> score; 

    std::vector<Player> players;
    std::set<CardData::Card> inPlay; // drawn cards inserted here to prevent duplication 

    CardData::Card drawCard();
    void hitOrStick();
    void playHands();
    int enumerateCard(const CardData::Card &card) const; // converts cards to score, deals with Aces and Royals
    void deal(Player &player); 

public:
    BlackJack(int players);
    void play();
};
```

BlackJack.cpp

```
#include "BlackJack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::unordered_map<Cards::Rank, int> BlackJack::score{
    {Cards::Rank::ONE, 1},{Cards::Rank::TWO, 2},{Cards::Rank::THREE, 3},
    {Cards::Rank::FOUR, 4},{Cards::Rank::FIVE, 5},{Cards::Rank::SIX, 6},
    {Cards::Rank::SEVEN, 7},{Cards::Rank::EIGHT, 8},{Cards::Rank::NINE, 9},
    {Cards::Rank::TEN, 10},{Cards::Rank::JACK, 10},{Cards::Rank::QUEEN, 10},
    {Cards::Rank::KING, 10},{Cards::Rank::ACE, 11}
};

BlackJack::BlackJack(int players = 2) : numPlayers(players) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        this->players.push_back(Player(i)); 
    }
}

void BlackJack::play() {
    // Shuffle workflow and distribute cards
    for (Player player : players) {
        std::cout << "Player \'" << player.getId() << "\' These are your cards: " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            deal(player);
        }
    }

    hitOrStick();
    playHands();
}

void BlackJack::deal(Player &player) {
    CardData::Card drawn;
    drawn = drawCard();
    while (inPlay.find(drawn) != inPlay.end())
        drawn = drawCard();

    std::cout << score[drawn.rank] << std::endl;
    player.dealtCard(drawn);
    player.updateScore(enumerateCard(drawn));
    inPlay.insert(drawn);
}

CardData::Card BlackJack::drawCard() {

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> suitDistrib(0, 3);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> rankDistrib(1, 14);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    int newRank = rankDistrib(generator);
    int newSuit = suitDistrib(generator);

    return CardData::Card{ static_cast<Cards::Rank>(newRank), static_cast<Cards::Suit>(newSuit) };
}

int BlackJack::enumerateCard(const CardData::Card &card) const {
    return score[card.rank];
}

void BlackJack::hitOrStick() {
    for (Player player : players) 
        while (!player.hasBust() && player.requestHit()) 
            deal(player);
}

void BlackJack::playHands() {
    int winner = -1;
    int maxScore = -1;
    bool push = false;

    for (Player player : players) {
        std::cout << "Player " << player.getId() << ": " << player.getScore() << std::endl;
        if (player.getScore() > maxScore) {
            push = false;
            winner = player.getId();
            maxScore = player.getScore();
        } else if (maxScore == player.getScore()) {
            push = true;
        }
    }

    if (push)
        std::cout << "Push!" << std::endl;
    else if (winner == 0)
        std::cout << "House wins!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Player " << winner << " wins!" << std::endl;
}
```

---

Any advice on what I need to improve or design/clean code faux pas I'm breaking? If you also having any suggestions on how I should focus on my dealer AI or operator< overload, I really appreciate. Here's to getting better every day!

Comment: `Right now it's a work in progress` Does it work?

Comment: @yuri each function works as intended, but to completion it doesn't. Right now I'm trying to figure out the overload for `bool operator<(const CardData::Card &card) const` so that the comparisons work correctly for the set and map containers.

Comment: Deja vu! I just reviewed [another Blackjack game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221454/console-blackjack-game-without-split-or-betting-system-for-now/221565#221565) probably a week ago! I think I like your design better. Anyway, if you want to see how someone else tried to accomplish the same thing, here you go.

Comment: @Chipster thanks, just having other references is helpful enough to see what may work or be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Recently I came to the realization that I been holding myself back by doing this and moving beyond my insecurities. I have taken more leaps by writing common C++ programs to build my knowledge of the language and architecture.

Learning by doing is a good approach IMO. 
Hopefully you can improve your game and submit it again for review!

---

### main

Is `Player.h` needed in main?

Turn `2` into a named constant:

```
int constexpr players{2};
BlackJack game{players};
```

This makes it much clearer what is being passed to your game.

While some people really don't like this, you can omit `return 0` from `main` if you don't depend on it. The compiler will generate it for you.

---

### cardinfo

Personally I don't mind `#pragma once`, just remember it's [not standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

[Subjective] Don't indent after `namespace`.

[Subjective] Don't write more than one statement per line in your enums.

If you want to use an unordered container with a custom key you need to provide *hash* and *compare* functions. Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) and this [link from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map).

---

### player

Class interfaces should go from least restricted to most restricted (i.e. `public`, `protected`, `private`). Reason being that when someone reads your interface he is most likely interested in the public functions that can be worked with.

[Subjective] Don't omit braces as that can lead to bugs down the line.
E.g.:

```
// bad
if (foo) 
    // code here

// good
if (foo)
{
    // code here
}
```

[Prefer prefix (++foo) over postfix (foo++) operator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator).

[Prefer using `\n` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

I'm not familiar with blackjack but if you ask *"hit or stick"* should the answer options really be *"yes/no"* not maybe *"hit/stick"*?

---

### blackjack

Reuse your RNG. Have a look at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213842/rock-paper-scissors-engine) to see how it could be done.

[You can and should use brace initialization when possible.](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax)

Comment: Thank you @yuri this was more than I was expecting. This should put me on the right track. This pretty much covers everything I been having uncertainty with. I'll be sure to submit my updates again.

Comment: I guess I'm in the crowd that doesn't like not returning from main. I think doing that might technically be undefined behavior, although since it's main, there may be an exception for that. I don't remember.

Comment: Nvm. I found where it said that in the standard. I guess I still don't like it, though :)